# Copy whole folder from source to destination and remove extra files or folder from destination

Tags: linux, shell-script, file-copy

I need to copy all files and directory from source let's say `/var/www/html/test/` to destination `/var/www/html/test2/`. Destination can already have extra files and folders which i need to remove after copying the files from source.

I cannot delete everything from destination before copying it.

**UPDATE**

I tried following :

1) Copied the file from source to destination using `cp`command

```
cp -R source destination
```

which working fine.

2) I tried to iterate over all the files in destination file to check if the file is exist in source. If not remove the file from destination

```
for file in /var/www/html/test2/*; 
  do filestr=`basename $file`;echo $file; 
  if [ `ls /var/www/test1/ | grep -c $filestr` -eq 0 ]; 
 then rm $file; fi; 
done;
```

which working fine for the root files in the destination only.

Need to find out how to recursively check all file and directory matching with source or not.

Comment: I adjusted my answer, try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="/var/www/html/test/"
DESTINATION="/var/www/html/test2/"

cp -pRu "$SOURCE*" "$DESTINATION"

HITSDIR=`find $DESTINATION -type d | sed -e 's|'$DESTINATION'\(.*\)|\1|g'`

for i in $HITSDIR; do
if [ -e $SOURCE$i ]; then
echo Yes $SOURCE$i exists
else
echo Nope delete $DESTINATION$i.
#rm -r $DESTINATION$i
fi
done

HITSFILES=`find $DESTINATION -type f | sed -e 's|'$DESTINATION'\(.*\)|\1|g'`

for i in $HITSFILES; do
if [ -e $SOURCE$i ]; then
echo Yes $SOURCE$i exists
else
echo Nope delete $DESTINATION$i.
#rm $DESTINATION$i
fi
done
```

This should do what you want, just uncomment the rm once you did a dry run.

Comment: This will not delete the not existing files...

Comment: Ye, I adjusted it to his requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much @ziazis. This solution is working perfectly for me. You saved my day.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is perfect when working on stations that do not have rsync

Answer (score 10):

This is a classic use case for `rsync`. `rsync` will copy a directory tree from source to destination. It can also be asked to delete excess *other* files after the copy:

```
rsync -a -v --delete-after /var/www/html/test/ /var/www/html/test2
```

Note the trailing `/` on the source specification. If you omit this, it'll copy the source directory itself, which you won't want.

If you want it to be quiet, remove the `-v`. If the files are large and compressible, you might want to try adding `-z` to get it to do compression and decompression, but I doubt it'll gain much. The `--delete-after` option deletes just the excess files and folders from the destination, but not until *after* the other files have been copied.

A bonus of using `rsync` is that it will not bother copying files that are the same (i.e. already there and that actually match).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But rsync is not installed on server and we are not allowed to do so. Is this possible by running some shell commands?

Comment: It's complicated to do the deletion part. It's probably time you pressed management to install `rsync`!

Comment: Maybe it's worth to try to just download your distributions `rsync` package, extract it and try to use it from your users folder.

Comment: `-z` is ignored for local filesystem copies. `rsync` won't check anything other than the file size and timestamp before deciding the contents are "the same". On a local to remote copy you can force a checksum comparison, but on local copies `rsync` simply recopies the files.

Comment: The use of `-z` is certainly pretty useless for local copies. However, I haven't seen that documented anywhere. I have done local copies and accidentally used `-z`, and there has been a small 'speedup' according to the stats from `-v`.

Comment: With `rsync` installed, this is a perfect answer.

Comment: The problem with `rsync` is that it is designed to check if a file has been changed and then copy parts of it. This takes a lot of time. `cp` should be faster.